# calculate next line numbers

Tags: for-loop, calculated-columns

Weird question I guess.. But I am not very math wiz - soo here goes..

I am trying to create a patterne (or variable patterns based on selection) based on x and y numbers (2 rows and 4 columns) and the direction of the counting of x numbers

All in PHP ;-)

like:

```
1-2-3-4
5-6-7-8
```

That one is easy, when number of x-columns is reached, next line and continue x count.

But with eg. this one (still 2 rows and 4 columns):

```
1-2-3-4
8-7-6-5
```

upsie.. what if it is eg. 3++ rows and still 4 columns?

```
1-2-3-4
8-7-6-5
9-10-11-12
```

what would be the formula for this - or other possible variations (teaser for variations):

```
9-10-11-12
8-7-6-5
1-2-3-4
```

or reversed

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you are saying here.  Do you need to calculate the next row by the previous row?  Do you need each row sorted?

Comment: What programming language?

Comment: Edited - for PHP and to show the direction .. Sorry..

Answer (score 0):

For the example you gave where every 2nd row is reversed, use:

```
int x;
for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < columnCount; j++)
    {
        if (i % 2 == 0) // Rows with even index
            x = (i * columnCount) + (j+1);
        else // Other rows (i.e. odd index)
            x = ((i+1) * columnCount) - (j+1);
    }
}
```

You haven't specified a programming language, but the answer looks roughly the same regardless.